# Android Linear Layout weight and soft keyboard issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to achieve the following view in a chat app. There are basically two states one with the soft touch keyboard showing and one without.

So this is my initial state without the keyboard showing.

[image]

This is what happens when the keyboard shows up.

[image]

This is what i'm trying to achieve.

[image]

**Note** 
I'm current using "adjust-resize" as the windowSoftInputMode. I know using "adjust-pan" will fix the issue, but with "adjust-pan" there are 2 problems :

1. The toolbar also moves up making space for the edit-text and keyboard.
2. The editText gets partly covered by the keyboard.

A layout experts help is needed here!
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

This is what my XML looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_group_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:elevation="4dip" >

            <!-- Toolbar stuff -->

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_group_toolbar"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6">

            <include
                layout="@layout/layout_that_covers_60%_of_the_screen (This is not my actual layout name :/ using it for understandability)"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_group_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <include
                layout="@layout/layout_that_covers_40%_of_the_screen"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="8dip" > 
            <!-- This is where my edit text resides -->

    </RelativeLayout> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: well structured question can you post your xml or root tag of it?

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your quick reply, I've edited the question to include my XML.  It's is a rough sketch of what my layout looks like.

Comment: try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248555/soft-keyboard-pushing-up-layout-or-hidding-action-bar)

Comment: @kishorejethava Setting the root-layout attribute "isScrollContainer" to "false" doesn't work because i'm using linear layouts and it respects the weight distribution none the less.

Comment: Try this Code may be it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/41038631/4427519

Comment: try with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"`

Comment: @kishorejethava  my current set-up is android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden

Comment: whats problem? it's working perfect in mine

Comment: Its working fine for me too. The thing is if you see the images above  LinearLayout 1 that covers 60 % of the screen shrinks to take up 60% of whatever the amount of space is left after the keyboard show up. I want this layout to get pushed above the visible screen just like how it would if i use "adjustPan"

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I think you should do,
use

windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" - The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen. Also adjustResize keeps the ToolBar on top.

Try adding both your LinearLayouts inside a NestedScrollView. The reason I say this is because your NestedScrollView contents can scroll up.

I think your Layout will look like this- .

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_group_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:elevation="4dip" >

        <!-- Toolbar stuff -->

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>


<NestedScrollView 
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_bar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view_group_toolbar">
  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">

        <include
            layout="@layout/layout_that_covers_60%_of_the_screen (This is not my actual layout name :/ using it for understandability)"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_group_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/layout_that_covers_40%_of_the_screen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="8dip" > 
        <!-- This is where my edit text resides -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

EDIT 1:
If you have a RecyclerView inside your layouts, you may need to set this attribute for smooth scroll -

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```